# Manually add a Z variable in Qgis onto a vector layer?

Tags: qgis, z-value

I am trying to manually add one constant Z-variable (e.g. 200meters) across an entire Vector Layer in Qgis so that I may eventually use the Interpolation plugin to generate a Tin.

I have not been able to find any information on how to do this on the website. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

As of version 2.10, QGIS supports Z and M values. (See corresponding [changelog entry](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog210/index.html#feature-new-geometry-engine))

In QGIS 3.4, there is a Processing tool called **[Set Z value](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#set-z-value)** to add a constant Z value and there is **[Drape](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z)** to add Z from a raster.

---

Old answer

Just add another attribute to the vector layer's attribute table and fill it with the value using Field Calculator. For help with the field calculator, please check the docs: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html

Note that QGIS does not support 3D geometries so you have to store your z value in the attribute table.

Comment: Does QGIS still not support 3D geometries in 2019?

Comment: @Stefan It does since version 2.10